# What is a "spirtual circle" in Ignatian Spirituality?

Tags: catholicism, ignatian-spirituality

I'm writing a speech on Ven. Jaques Sevin for a presentation, reading about him [here](https://www.cics.org/?wpfb_dl=18) which is not a broken link, but a bad PDF that you have to hack apart in notepad and resave as a PDF to read.  It says that

> He conducts a spiritual Circle, the fruit of a long maturing process of the work of the Holy Spirit within himself and the Ignatius obedience

Can someone tell me, in layman's terms, what this looks like?  Do all Jesuits, who live long enough, do this? Is it the culmination of something?

Comment: I did the hacking and put the PDF [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fopsG-aQMeuGS4QQiDMY1Sucs0IZgupq/view?usp=sharing)